# Error when running or debugging Unit tests Visual Studio 2017

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

There is an Error in the output window while running or debugging tests

`Error IUnitTestStorage.Open should be called before operation can continue.`

even the test cases are not shown in the Test Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: it didn't work, only it works when closing visual studio and opening it again